# How can I hide tooltip in highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I want a tooltip to hide when the cursor is moved, but the column remains selected

```
$(function () {

        Highcharts.Pointer.prototype.reset = function () {

        };
        let chart = Highcharts.chart('bar', {


            tooltip: {
                shared: true,
                hideDelay:100,
                useHTML: true,
                outside: true,
                style: {
                    fontSize: "13px",
                    color: '#505050'
                }
            },
        });

});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/alexserden/wq6j0tnp/6/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prepare a demo with custom function which hides tooltip when mouse leaves the chart container.

```
  events: {
    load() {
      let chart = this;

      chart.container.onmouseleave = function() {
        chart.series[0].points.forEach(p => {
          if(p.state === 'hover') {
            chart.tooltip.hide(p)
          }
        })
      }
    }
  }
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/0ag7ojmy/

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.load

Comment: i think the question was how to remove the tooltip straight up, not when you trigger mouseout when exiting the chart with your mouse